# How can I redirect a page to an external url AEM6.1

Tags: aem

I need to redirect an AEM page to an external URL. For eg., I have a page /content/test, and I have to redirect it to  http://www.google.com/. How can I do that?

Basically, when someone hits that page, it should get redirected to  http://www.google.com/

Can I use vanity URLs for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are extending from the foundation page component, you can specify the redirect in the `Advanced` tab of the page properties. This would behave similar to a 301 redirect.

[image]

Another way of doing the same would be do define `/etc/map` configurations.

However, I would prefer having the redirect configured in the Web Server ([Apache vhost file](https://serverfault.com/questions/120488/redirect-url-within-apache-virtualhost)) or CDN itself (if there is one) so that the request doesn't reach AEM servers.

Comment: Thanks rakhi4110. Can I do a redirect to an external site in Web server( in dispatcher file). If yes, can you please provide me the syntax.                       Also, If I am using redirect option in Advanced tab, the page is not redirecting to the google.com automatically, instead it is showing "This page is set to redirect to http://www.google.com".

Comment: In author instance it wouldn't redirect, instead shows that message. When you view the same page in publish, it would redirect. Or you can use `?wcmmode=disabled` query param to verify the same. And yes you can redirect to external site as well in Web Server, but it is not configured in the dispatcher. It has to be configured in the [vhost file](http://serverfault.com/questions/120488/redirect-url-within-apache-virtualhost)